# SSH Ubuntu -> Windows XP -> Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, sync

I'm developing cross-platform, and I have the following situation:

1. a PC with Windows 7 + Ubuntu in a virtual machine where I develop and compile the code located in the office
2. a PC with Windows XP in the lab
3. an embedded device running Linux with buttons that I need to press

What I normally do is to make changes in Ubuntu, send them via SSH to the embedded device, walk from the office to the lab, open Putty on the Windows XP, and run the program and press the buttons in the embedded system to try the changes. I'm getting tired of walking!

I cannot install new stuff in the lab computer, but I have Notepad++ that would do for simple changes. How can I sync the code between the Ubuntu virtual machine, Windows XP and an embedded system? Can I compile using Ubuntu from the Windows XP machine?

Comment: Why do you have to run the program from Putty on WinXP? Why can't you do it from Ubuntu from the same SSH session?

Comment: The program runs on the embedded system. I can run it from both, it's not a problem. But I need to use xp to see something more user friendly than putty. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you find unfriendly about using SSH on Ubuntu, but if you want something that can help you manage SSH sessions from the GUI, [SecPanel](http://themediahost.de/secpanel/) will help (it's in the [repos](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/secpanel/)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.
What I'm doing to deal with this is to share a folder between ubuntu and winxp.
access to ubuntu and the embedded system with putty from xp. Compile in ubuntu and edit the code in xp with notepad++.